# Using exceptions in a production environment: Can a try catch block 'return' booleans?

Tags: php, oop, exception, paypal, boolean

The app is built on the MVC pattern, so my controllers are separate from my models.

I am using two payment gateways, Stripe and PayPal and have moved the API code into a model called Payment_Model.php.

Both functions have huge try/catch blocks that throw all manner of errors when a payment fails which is a good thing for me, not so for a customer...

Here is a try catch block example

```
     try {

        Stripe::setApiKey($this->config->item('stripe_secret_key'));

        $customer = Customer::create([
            'email'  => 'customer@example.com',
            'source' => $this->input->post('stripe_token'),
        ]);

        $charge = Charge::create([
            'customer'    => $customer->id,
            'amount'      => $option->price,
            'currency'    => 'eur',
            "description" => "Demo Transaction", // @TODO
        ]);

    } catch (Exception $e) {

    } catch (Stripe_CardError $e) {
        throw new Exception($e);
    } catch (Stripe_InvalidRequestError $e) {
        throw new Exception($e);
    } catch (Stripe_AuthenticationError $e) {
        throw new Exception($e);
    } catch (Stripe_ApiConnectionError $e) {
        throw new Exception($e);
    } catch (Stripe_Error $e) {
        throw new Exception($e);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception($e);
    }
```

I don't want to display these errors or exceptions in my production environment... instead I would like to replace `throw new Exception($e)` with `false` so that I can call the model function in my controller and if something goes wrong I can redirect the user to a decent error page...

**So my question is this:**

Can I return a boolean IF something bad is caught so that I can either redirect to a success page or an error page in my controller? Or am I missing the point of using exceptions?

Comment: Certainly you can. You are free to do whatever you want inside your catch block. No one forces you to re-throw the exception. Typically you want to take some data from the exception object and do something with it (file logging for example), and then dispose the object.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of exceptions. Mainly don't catch them just to re-throw them, that's pointless.

Comment: @arkascha thanks, logging the data makes sense, probably in unison with an email alert.

Comment: @apokryfos sorry, that code came with the tutorial I was following!

Comment: Good read: [The (im)proper use of try..catch.](https://phpdelusions.net/delusion/try-catch)

Comment: I suggest to not try-catch in the model at all and do that in the controller, and determine (based on the exception) what sort of user-friendly and informative error page to display, e.g. `Stripe_AuthenticationError` would probably be a 403 page with a message which is useful to the user. Any exception which does not correspond to anything useful for the user should just not be handled by you and you should let it be handled by a global exception handler.